# How to proxy request to different services on same url using Ocelot base on client ip

Tags: ocelot

I have configuration below

```
{
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api{catchall}",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "my-order-webapi-service",
                "Port": 8080,
            }
        ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/order{catchall}",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ]
}
```

Due to change of business, I add a new api service. And I need to proxy all request from a list of ip to the new service. What changes should I make to the config?

Maybe like this?

```
{
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api{catchall}",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "my-new-order-webapi-service",
                "Port": 8080,
            }
        ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/order{catchall}",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ],
    "UpstreamHost": ["10.172.44.56", "10.72.44.55"] // source ip difference here
},
{
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api{catchall}",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "my-order-webapi-service",
                "Port": 8080,
            }
        ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/order{catchall}",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ]
}
```